# Bootstrap 3 Autocomplete not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-9

I have developed a website using bootstrap 3 with php and database MSSQL Server 2008 R2. The data is coming from database successfully.

PROBLEM: When i start typing in input field it does not show autocomplete in IE9.

Example: Input field dropdown is fetching data from database brining project ID. once i start typing 49 it displays all the projct ID starting with 49 i.e. autocomplete if thats what you call it.

This feature is working correctly in firefox and chrome.

i have already added the respond.min.js and html5shiv.js so the layout is fine but having issue with autocomplete.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Enable auto complete feature for the input fields. Add autocomplete="on" to the input fields.

Comment: I have used it and it still doesnt work. I even updated IE9 to IE10. code for input is <input id="search_project" name="search_project" type="text" list="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Project ID" autocomplete="on" />